# footer width and color

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I have a further problem with my beamer style.

So basically, I am trying to include a gray footer, where I include name, short title and frame numbers.

Therefore I split the footer in two parts using the following:

```
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode
  \hbox{  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{title in head/foot}    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{18em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{5ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}
  \vskip0pt
}
\makeatletter
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{use=structure,fg=red,bg=gray!10!white}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{use=structure,fg=red,bg=gray!10!white}
```

The result is as follows:
[image]

Basically, I cannot extend the two parts of the footer to cover the white and red indicated by the two arrows.

I am using scientific workplace with Singapore theme. I post the entire preamble of my file in case it is useful, although it is a bit messy at the moment.

```
\newenvironment{stepenumerate}{\begin{enumerate}[<+->]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemize}{\begin{itemize}[<+->]}{\end{itemize} }
\newenvironment{stepenumeratewithalert}{\begin{enumerate}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemizewithalert}{\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{itemize} }
\usetheme{Singapore}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[$ball$]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{$-$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{$*$}
\definecolor{unime}{rgb}{.93,.9,.0}
\usecolortheme[named=unime]{structure}
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=lside}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{use=structure,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=lside} 
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=lside} 
\setbeamercolor{itemize subsubitem}{fg=lside}
\definecolor{lside}{rgb}{.7,.0,.0}
\definecolor{leftFootlineColor}{rgb}{.54,.17, .89}
\useoutertheme[width=1.3cm,height=35pt,left]{sidebar}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=unime}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=leftFootlineColor}
\setbeamercolor{title}{use=structure,fg=black}
\logo {\includegraphics[height=1.3cm,width=1.3cm]{uni}}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left} [vertical shading]
[top=lside, bottom=lside]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\graphicspath{{c:/}}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\beamer@headheight}{1.3cm}
\makeatother
\newlength\sidebarwd
\setlength\sidebarwd{1.3cm}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\sidebarwd}
\makeatletter
\setlength\beamer@sidebarwidth{\sidebarwd}
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=lside}
\makeatletter 
  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}
  {
    \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -6pt
    \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}
    \vfill
    \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext
    \else
      \usebeamercolor{normal text}
      \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}
      \vskip2pt
    \fi
  }
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode
  \hbox{  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{title in head/foot}    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{18em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{5ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}
  \vskip0pt
}
\makeatletter
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{use=structure,fg=red,bg=gray!10!white}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{use=structure,fg=red,bg=gray!10!white}
\input{tcilatex}
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Dario

Comment: Try to remove the empty spaces inside `\hbox{}`. `\hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\end{beamercolorbox}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{title in head/foot}\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{18em}\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{5ex}\end{beamercolorbox}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It works fine now. I could not figure out there where empty spaces.

Comment: You started your box with blank space and also after you end the first and before to start the second box.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I removed all of them.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

You inserted some blank spaces before the 1st box and also between the 1st and 2nd boxes.

If you remove them inserting comment sign `%` at the end of line you can solve the problem.

With `%` at the end the code in the next line is executed *exactly* after the previous one.

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
\leavevmode
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]%
  {author in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}%
  \insertshortauthor%
\end{beamercolorbox}%               <-- no blank space here
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]%
  {title in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}%
  \insertshorttitle%
  \hspace*{18em}%
  \insertframenumber\ / \inserttotalframenumber%
  \hspace*{5ex}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\vskip0pt
}
```

[image]